# Making copy selector like seen on blog.google.com

Tags: javascript, copy, tooltip, share

In [blog.google.com](https://blog.google.com) 
They have this stunning yet useful copy share selector that looks resembles a tooltip,
[here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOmDU.png)
Can somebody help me out on the JS, I dont know where to start!